# Does Halakhah require one to believe in Gilu'i Eliyahu, Gilu'i Maggid, and the like?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, agada-stories-legends, eliyahu-hanavi

I have heard many stories from many independent sources about Rabbis receiving teachings via individual revelation in the form of *Gilu'i Eliyahu* (i.e. "the appearance of Eliyahu") or *Gil'ui Maggid* (e.g. the AR"I, the Ba`al Shem Tov, R' Shalom Shar`abi, R' Yosef Qaro, etc.).

Does Halakhah require one to believe that such forms of individual revelation are indeed possible? If so, how can one verify the authenticity of such claims?

Comment: Proving the negative is very difficult.Which halakha do you think might include this?